# Button Column in DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i am trying to set the text of all the buttons to "Set Text". I have made this, but it did not work....How would i do this?

```
        foreach (DataGridViewButtonCell btn in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            btn.Text = "Set Text"; 
        }
```

Also, how would i have an onclick event for those buttons?

Comment: We need to see more.  ASPX code for the grid and code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[0];//Column Index
                cell.Value = "Set Text";
            }
        }
```

result:

[image]

and for On click event:

```
private void gw_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)//Column index
            {
                //Do Somethings
            }
        }
```

Comment: You missed the onclick event part.

Answer (score 2):

Change the button text.

```
const int BUTTON_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[BUTTON_COLUMN_INDEX].Value = "Set Text";
}
```

You cannot have a button click even in  a DataGridView. 
Instead you must handle the `CellClick` event and check if the column you want was clicked.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    // Check if wanted column was clicked 
    if (e.ColumnIndex == BUTTON_COLUMN_INDEX && e.RowIndex >= 0) {
        //Perform on button click code
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for adding the && e.RowIndex >= 0 ... it turns out, i needed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
        foreach (DataGridViewButtonCell btn in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            btn.Text = "Set Text";
            btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue=true;
        }
```